# If I drive through a pit, do I die?

Tags: robo-rally

In Robo Rally, if I don't end in but rather drive through a pit, do I die? Instructions seem to literally say if they move into, but I'm not clear if it's strictly if they end there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you drive over a pit, gravity wins.

This is a game, not a cartoon.

This is mentioned in the [rules](https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/roborally.pdf) page 8.

> Destruction: A robot is destroyed when:
>
> - It receives its tenth Damage token.  OR
> - It moves or is moved into a pit.  OR
> - It moves or is moved oﬀ the edge of the board.

In the original version, there where pits that could be opened and closed, not sure if they still exist. But these where safe when closed but deadly when open.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the rules for this?

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I added the reference.

Comment: The OP had already seen those rules, and was just wondering exactly what "into" meant. It certainly makes physical sense, as you say. If you want to try to get it out of the rules, though, the thing that really clinches it is that pits are *not* mentioned in the turn order (robots move, board elements move, lasers fire, etc). If they were meant to only kill you after you were done moving, they'd presumably be somewhere in that detailed list after the roibots move part. The fact that they aren't suggests that you die while moving.

Comment: @Jefromi, I have the first version, and those rules are more explicit. (Unfortunately I can't reach them right now).